# Boostrap: Text overflows out of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following mark up which works fine when I view the page in full screen

[image]

, but when I decrease the width of the browser, it spills out of the div.

[image]

I've used white-space: normal on panel-body but it doesn't work. text-overflow: ellipsis doesn't do anything either. I'm using Bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <section class="panel" style="background:#e74c3c; color:#FFF;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            COMPLAINT<br>
            8
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

```
.col-sm-4 {
    width: 33.33333333333333%;
}

.panel-body {
    padding: 15px;
}

.panel {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: it is working fine. what you want?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LwqQh/

Comment: Setting `min-width` instead of `width` and `display: inline-block` for `.col-sm-4` will stop the text from spilling out by not making the element smaller if the text is too big. I have the feeling that is not exactly what you are looking for though. http://jsfiddle.net/fS8Xw/

Answer (score 6):

For `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work you have to add a `overflow: hidden` setting to that element.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/35kUW/)

[image]

```
.panel-body {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either put `word-wrap: break-word;` on `.panel-body`, however this may make the text very hard to read. Alternatively you could put a `min-width` on the container of `.col-sm-4` to prevent it becoming too small to fit the text in.

Comment: A `div` element (or any block) by default gobbles up as much space as you give it, so it needs to be an `inline-block` if you go with `min-width`.

Answer (score 0):

If your using word-break break-all means word will cut off so you can give proper width in percentage value then also problem means use text-overflow:ellipsis.

Example:

```
.col-sm-4 {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when working on a **Rails 6** application with **Bootstrap**:

I simply defined a custom CSS class:

```
.remove_overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and applied the custom CSS class to the form element:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.label :body %>
  <%= form.rich_text_area :body, class: 'form-control hide_overflow' %>
</div>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**